# Why RedirectResult is not working well in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, iis-7

I'm working in a session code. When my session finish, then goes to global.asax and redirect to an specific relative URL.

The redirection works, but when it redirects, the page can not be found.

What is wrong with my code?

Both are not working, neather with HTTP and my IP neather relative path.

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            // check  sessions here
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UsuarioActual"] == null)
            {
                 //filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("[http ip here]");
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login");
                return;
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

In my global.asax i have this

```
   GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new SessionExpireAttribute());
```

Comment: `new RedirectResult("/Account/Login");`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's a shrewd guess but more information is needed

Comment: Step 1 is to figure out if the 302 redirect header contains the correct string. If it does, most of the example in this question are not helpful-- we'd need to see the routing config that is failing to match on the URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it replacing this

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(LoginRougte());
```

By this

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Login/LogOut");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private RouteValueDictionary LoginRougte()
    {
        return new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            {"action", "Login"},
            {"controller", "Account"},
            {"area", ""}
        };
    }

    private readonly List<string> _exceptCtrls = new List<string> { "userauth", "manager", "account" };

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var routeData = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        var controller = routeData != null ? routeData.Values["controller"] as string : string.Empty;
        var check = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller) && !_exceptCtrls.Contains(controller.ToLower());

        if (check && (HttpContext.Current.Session == null || HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys.Count == 0))
        {                
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(LoginRougte());
        } 
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

This code from my live project. It's work form me. Hopefully it's also work for you.

Comment: is working well, but still is not redirecting me well, i don't know why... i have the SessionExpireAttribute into Model folder... I don't know if that is the problem... **"The page could not be found... Try removing cookies"**

Comment: @WhiteKnight r u change the `RouteValueDictionary` value in `LoginRougte()`. i think you need to change `action` and `controller` name as your project.